# CloudPages keeps adding max-width property

Tags: marketing-cloud, css, landing-page

CloudPages keeps adding a `max-width` property to the style tag in my page. It is part of the `main_style` class and keeps getting inserted every time I open the code. I can delete it and publish the code without it, but if I re-open the code for the page and forget to delete it one time, it will be published with the page which is really annoying.

Is there any way I can get rid of that permanently? I am talking about the `max-width` property for `body` here:

```
 <style class="main_style">
    body { font-family: Arial; margin: 0px auto; background-color: #E4E4E4; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; color: #808080; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1; padding: 0px; max-width: 1280px; } 
    ...
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that this can be bypassed by overwriting the CSS setting for `max-width` in the `<body >` tag. Since HTML is read from top to bottom, the in-line setting in `body` will overwrite the previous setting.

Therefore: Fix the in-line styling to `max-width: 100%` in `<body style="..">`.